# How do I use django.core.urlresolvers.reverse with a function reference instead of a named URL pattern?

Tags: python, django

In my `urls.py` file, I have:

```
from myapp import views
...
(r'^categories/$', views.categories)
```

Where `categories` is a view function inside `myapp/views.py`. No other URLconf lines reference `views.categories`.

In a unit test file, I’m trying to grab this URL using `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()`, instead of just copying '/categories/' (DRY and all that). So, I have:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from myapp import views
...

url = reverse(views.categories)
```

When I run my tests, I get a `NoReverseMatch` error:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '<function categories at 0x1082f30>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

It matches just fine if I make the URL pattern a named pattern, like this:

```
url(r'^categories/$', views.categories, 'myapp-categories')
```

And use the pattern name to match it:

```
url = reverse('myapp-categories')
```

But as far as I can tell from [the `reverse` documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse), I shouldn’t need to make it a named URL pattern just to use `reverse`.

Any ideas what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: The reverse documentation states taht you need to use named URLs or pass the name of the function used in your URLconf, and it can be passed as a string. So either make it a named URL or use "views.categories".

Comment: The latest documentation says the view name is “either a function reference, or the string version of the name”, so it shouldn’t need to be a string: <http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/?from=olddocs#reverse>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After futher investigation, turns out it was an issue with how I was importing the views module:

[How do I successfully pass a function reference to Django’s reverse() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146522/how-do-i-successfully-pass-a-function-reference-to-djangos-reverse-function)

Thanks for the help though, guys: you inspired me to look at it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Jack M.'s example is nearly correct.

It needs to be a url function, not a tuple, if you want to use named urls.

```
url(r'^no_monkeys/$', 'views.noMonkeys', {}, "no-monkeys"),
```

Answer (score 0):

This does work, and all the code that you've pasted is correct and works fine (I just copied it into a clean test/project app and it reversed the URL without any problem).  So there's something else going on here that you haven't showed us.  Simplify down to the bare-bones basics until it works, then start adding complexity back in and see where it's breaking.

Also, you can do "./manage.py shell" and then interactively import the reverse function and your view function and try the reverse.  That'll remove the test setup as a possible cause.

Comment: You’re quite right: I’m a bit new to programming, so often I forget the proper troubleshooting steps like that. It’s weird though, I’ve created a new, empty one-app project, pasted the code in, and I can’t get it working there either. I’ll fiddle some more.

Answer (score -1):

The reverse function actually uses the "name" of the URL.  This is defined like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^no_monkeys/$', 'views.noMonkeys', {}, "no-monkeys"),
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
)
```

Now you would call reverse with the string "no-monkeys" to get the correct url.

Ninja Edit:  [Here is a link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2) to the django docs on the subject.

Comment: Sure, it seems to work fine if I use named URL patterns. But I think it should work just with a function reference.

As a side note,  I think you need to use the URL function instead of just a tuple to create named URL pattern i.e.

    url(r'^no_monkeys/$', 'views.noMonkeys', {}, "no-monkeys")

Comment: Yes, you need to call `the url()` function to use named URLs, as I have stated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134629/how-do-i-use-djangocoreurlresolversreverse-with-a-function-reference-instead-of#136721

Comment: And, `name` is a keyword argument and must be signed as such.